# OneToMany relation_id return Null

Tags: forms, symfony, foreign-keys

I'm new to `Symfony2`. I have problem about `One-To-Many` relationship.

My code is,

Here, Product-Size, product_id return null.

**Product Entity** :

```
namespace Front\ProductBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Product
{
  //
  /**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Size", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
  */
  public $size;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->size = new ArrayCollection();
  }
  /**
   * Add size
   *
   * @param Front\ProductBundle\Entity\Size $size
   */
  public function addSize(\Front\ProductBundle\Entity\Size $size)
  {
      $this->size[] = $size;
  }

  /**
   * Get size
   *
   * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
   */
  public function getSize()
  {
      return $this->size;
  }
}
```

**Size Entity**:

```
namespace Front\ProductBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
class Size
{
//
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="size", cascade={"persist"})
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected $product;

  /**
  * Set product
  *
  * @param Front\ProductBundle\Entity\Product $product
  */
  public function setProduct(\Front\ProductBundle\Entity\Product $product)
  {
    $this->product = $product;
  }

  /**
   * Get product
   *
   * @return Front\ProductBundle\Entity\Product
   */
  public function getProduct()
  {
      return $this->product;
  }
}
```

**My Controller**:

```
namespace Admin\ProductBundle\Controller;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

// Entity
use Front\ProductBundle\Entity\Product;
use Front\ProductBundle\Entity\Size;

use Admin\ProductBundle\Form\Type\ProductType;
use Admin\ProductBundle\Form\Type\SizeType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;


class AdminController extends Controller
{
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
      $category = new Category();
      $product = new Product();

      //make 3 size for product
      $size1 = new Size();
      $product->addSize($size1);

      $size2 = new Size();
      $product->addSize($size2);

      $size3 = new Size();
      $product->addSize($size3);

      $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);

      //write data
      if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
          $form->bindRequest($request);

          //check validate
          if ($form->isValid()){
            //persist data() to database
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $product->upload();
            $em->persist($product);
            $em->flush();

            //set Message Flash and redirect
            $this->get('session')->setFlash('notice_success', 'Success Message ');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_admin_home'));
          }
        }


        return $this->render('AdminProductBundle:Admin:create.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

**My View**:

```
...
<div>
{% for size in form.size %}
  <div id="sizeField">
    <div class="blockSizeForm">
     {{ form_label(size.name) }}
     {{ form_widget(size.name) }}
   </div>
   <div class="blockSizeForm">
     {{ form_label(size.price) }}
     {{ form_widget(size.price) }}
       </div>
     </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Product Form and Size Form:

**Product Form**:

```
namespace Admin\ProductBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('size', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new SizeType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ));
    }
    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
        'data_class' => 'Front\ProductBundle\Entity\Product',
        'error_bubbling'=>true,
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Product';
    }
}
```

**Size Form**:

```
namespace Admin\ProductBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SizeType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name','text',array(
                'label' => 'name:',
                ))
            ->add('price','money',array(
                'label' => 'value:',
                ));
    }
    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
        'data_class' => 'Front\ProductBundle\Entity\Size',
        'error_bubbling'=>true,
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Size';
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**:
I can create new success. But product_id for Size table return Null.

help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you save entities in doctrine, the owning side must persist the relationship: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

In your code, the owning side is the Size entity as the entity with the `ManyToOne` description above the parameter is always the owning side.  This means you need to persist the Size entities not the product entities.

I think something like:

```
      if ($form->isValid()){
        //persist data to database            
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $product->upload();
        // loop through as set the relationship for each size
        foreach($product->getSize() as $size){
          $size->setProduct($product);
        }
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();

        //set Message Flash
        $this->get('session')->setFlash('notice_success', 'Success Message ');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_admin_home'));
      }
```

Your cascade persist should take care of the rest

Comment: your code works perfect and My problem has solved, thank you so much.